# PHP: Make variable accessible in object without passing it, or using $GLOBALS

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, scope

I have a variable that I need to access throughout an object tree. My design may look sort of weird at first, but I am trying to create an interface/API, that's accessible with as few lines of code as possible, as well as easily configurable. So bear with me...

```
Class GrandParent{
  public function original(){
    $myVar = 'I am needed throughout this method and within the config file';
    require('config.php');
  }
}

Class Parent{
  public function passObj($obj){
     //perform actions on obj.
  }
  public function output(){
     //I really need to know the value of $myVar;
     return $stuff;
  }
}

Class Child{
  public function __construct(){
     //I really need to know the value of $myVar;
  }
}

// config.php:

$parent = new Parent();
$child = new Child();
$parent->passObj($child);
return $parent->output();

// the use case:

$grandparent = new GrandParent($myVar);
echo $grandparent->orignial();
```

Again: With this design I am focusing on the developer who should be able to easily modify a config file (while keeping it short and only to the necessities) and call one method on the Grandparent Object ("the use case"), to get the desired output. The whole construct should be simple to use for a developer. Everything does depend on $myVar though. Of course I'd still like to be able to keep each class encapsulated.

**How do I make `$myVar` accessible to all object instances created in the config script**

- Without passing the variable a bunch of times (I want to keep config short and simple, without repetitive code)
- without using $GLOBALS (though to me it seems right now this may be the easiest/best solution... :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

You could be using the Singleton pattern.

With this pattern you have the possibility to do things like this:

```
GrandParent::getInstance()->original();
```

Comment: I would have to create a class that only contains the variable, right? Pretty much turn the variable into an object

Comment: I see you added code to your answer: Sorry, but the GrandParent Object should not be global. Just the variable myVar

Comment: Yes, that is one possibility. Another is that you have a class with an array with these variables, if you want to store more variables.

Comment: This way you are not really making your object global. The pattern was created with the idea to making it at the moment you need it, and not having to create it again. If this pattern doesn't fit your needs, I can not think of another solution right now :(

Comment: Well yea, the GrandParent object wouldn't technically be "global" when using singleton. Sorry... I do like the idea of making my variable an object, and then either using singleton or dependency injection to access this object. So thanks! :-) Will see if there's maybe a different idea though...

Comment: why don't you use getter and setter in your grandPa class ?